# Running a gradle clean shows a failure with ProcessLogger

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

This worked before, recently upgraded Android SDK & gradle.

```
~/app:../gradlew clean uploadHockeyDebugToHockeyApp --stacktrace
WARNING: WARNING: Dependency commons-logging:commons-logging:1.1.1 is ignored for hockeyDebug as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.

AILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':mobile:clean'.
> Unable to delete directory: /Users/quantum/app/mobile/build/intermediates/exploded-aar

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':mobile:clean'.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:69)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:46)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:35)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:64)
```

I tried commenting out

//    compile files('libs/commons-io-2.4.jar')

in my dependencies and I get

```
UnknownServiceException: No service of type ProgressLoggerFactory available in ProjectScopeServices.

Caused by: org.gradle.internal.service.UnknownServiceException: No service of type ProgressLoggerFactory available in ProjectScopeServices.
```

Comment: Is your project a multi- or single-project build?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try deleting the `build` folder yourself, as suggested in [other](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26192986/5115932) [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36594238/5115932) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36504095/5115932).

To do this first exit Android Studio, then navigate to the `/Users/quantum/app/mobile/` directory and delete the `build` folder.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

After updating gradle if Android Studio version is 2.0 Beta, this issue might appear (more likely if you are working on NTFS filesystem) and it seems like the "Instant Run" is the culprit. Search for "Instant Run" in settings and uncheck the box.

Clean project from Terminal using this command 'gradlew clean'.

Comment: I'm on Android Studio 2.2, the latest version. Instant Run is disabled.

Comment: Can you share your build.gradle file?